# discord.py как подключать бота к определенному голосовому каналу?

Tags: python, discord.py, radio

мне нужно подключить бота к определенному голосовому каналу, определенному значит: без ctx.message.author.voice.channel мне нужно чтобы он подключался сам в определенный момент, это нужно потому что он периодически вылетает с каналов, а мне нужно чтобы он сидел на них 24/7, код:

```
import os
import keep_alive
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.utils import get
import discord
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = ('')

client = Bot(command_prefix="8")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Music Bot Ready')
    await client.change_presence(status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game("Создатель: Cameta#4644"))


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx):
  global voice
  channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
  voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)
  if voice and voice.is_connected():
    await voice.move_to(channel)
  else:
    voice = await channel.connect()
  voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio('http://ep128.hostingradio.ru:8030/ep128'))

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def stop(ctx):
    voice.stop()

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def info(ctx):
  await ctx.send('8play - включить бота, 8stop - выключить бота')


keep_alive.keep_alive()  
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто вместо `await channel.connect()` напишите `await channel.connect(reconnect=True, timeout=None)` и бот ливать не должен.